# Why does Chrome overwrite my css, changing html,body height from 100% to auto or number in Rails erb

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I have a rails web page where I wanted to make the DIVs full screen, so I made html,body height to 100%. But what I got from Chrome browser was not 100%, it was auto in the original page since it was large, it's 484px in this test page since it's small.

Here is the code I got from Chrome:

```
<html style="height: 484px;">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body, html {
        height: 100%;
    }
    </style>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="chrome-extension://cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="chrome-extension://cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg/page_context.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
    <script>window["_GOOG_TRANS_EXT_VER"] = "1";</script>
    </head>
    <body screen_capture_injected="true">
        <div class="title">
            <div>
                <a href="/library">Library</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div id="GOOGLE_INPUT_CHEXT_FLAG" style="display: none;" input="" input_stat="{}"></div><div style="clear: both;"></div><iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="background-color: transparent; border: 0px; box-sizing: content-box; width: 152px; height: 29px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 2px 4px 0px; z-index: 2147483643; margin: 0px; position: fixed; left: 1234px; top: 405px; display: none;"></iframe><iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="background-color: transparent; border: 0px; display: none; box-sizing: content-box; width: 427px; height: 299px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 4px 16px 0px; z-index: 2147483640; margin: 0px; position: fixed;"></iframe><iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="background-color: transparent; border: 0px; display: none; box-sizing: content-box; width: 67px; height: 66px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 4px 16px 0px; z-index: 2147483644; margin: 0px; position: absolute;"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

See the "height: 484px;"? That was added by Chrome. I don't see it from Safari or Firefox. And there are also several its tags/styles added. I bet this has something to do with the height number.

But with the same content, I don't have any problem with static html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body, html {
        height: 100%;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="title">
        <div>
            <a href="/library">Library</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, I can fix this with !important after the 100% height but I still want to know why Chrome is that and how to turn it off, hopefully with some config like: -webkit-appearance: none; or something, but that doesn't work.

Btw, I'm on Chrome 29.0.1547.76 for Mac, Rails 4.0.0.

Appreciate if any input.

Please let me know if my information is not enough also.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have demo page that I can inspect the element?